# Battery 15 volts plus

Tags: battery

My car battery is running a 15.5 volts all the time yet at times has a slight struggle to start. It's been really cold lately in the teens and colder. Is my battery bad? Car was put in service in June of 2011 so it's almost 8 years old now.

Comment: 15.5V is not possible with a normal car battery - unless that is being measured while the engine is running which then says little about the battery itself.

Answer (score 1):

Any lead storage battery over five years old is suspect.  In my 30 years' experience, waiting until eight years to replace the battery always leads to trouble.